# Migrating to webpack 2 and encountered Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Error console appears after migrating to webpack 2 as below.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

[image: screen shot 2017-01-25 at 3 13 05 pm]

I made a few change to webpack.config following migration guide.
Here's the my PR for that changes https://github.com/mz026/universal-redux-template/pull/48/files

The app itself works so far so good but error console never disappears.

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin')

var DEBUG = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
var env = {
  NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  API_BASE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_URL
}

var config = {
  devtool: DEBUG ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : false,
  entry: {
    app: './app/app',
    vendor: [
      'react',
      'react-router',
      'redux',
      'react-dom',
      'lodash',
      'bluebird',
      'humps',
      'history'
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': JSON.stringify(env)
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'babel-loader' }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      }
    ]
  }
}

if (DEBUG) {
  config.entry.dev = [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  ]

  config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filname: 'vendor.js'
    })
  ])
  config.output.publicPath = 'http://localhost:3001/static/'
  config.module.rules[0].use[0].options = {
    "env": {
      "development": {
        "presets": ["react-hmre"]
      }
    }
  }
} else {
  config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filname: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
    }),
  ])
}

module.exports = config
```

It seems front-end code is not bundled properly. I think it is related to ES6 module import.

Comment: Instead of doing `module.rules.use` why no just `loader: "babel-loader"`?

Comment: @AndrewLi Can you explain me a little more? So far as I know, `module.loaders.loader` should be changed to `module.rules.use`